# Laptop Brightness not remembered on Power Plugged in

Tags: power-management, 14.10, brightness, tlp

On Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic, using a Samsung Notebook laptop, I can change the brightness correctly and it is remembered upon wake from sleep.

*However* my problem is that when my laptop is on battery and I plug it into a power source, the brightness returns to full *and remains there even when I unplug it!*

When I press a brightness key, it then suddenly remembers and then jumps back to what it should be.

*How do I get rid of this annoying behaviour?*

Note: I am using TLP.

Comment: Note: This problem is fixed as of 15.04, just upgrade.

Comment: You should make that an answer, not a comment!  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem with brightness has been corrected as of 15.04, upgrading is the easiest fix.